# Check condition in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, if-statement, conditional-statements

Basically i have a factory

```
angular.module('app').factory('gService',gService);
function gService($filter, $window) {
    function confirmDialog(message, success, fail) {
        var confirmMessage = navigator.notification.confirm(
                message,
                onConfirm,
                '',
                [$filter('translate')('OK'), $filter('translate')('CANCEL')]
            );
        function onConfirm(index) {         
            return index === 1 ? success() : fail();
        }
        return confirmMessage;
    }
}
```

I want to check condition outside this factory, if the functions are executed or not

```
if(gService.confirmDialog.onConfirm){

}
```

this does not work. How do i check function which is executed in angular?

Comment: what is index there??

Comment: Its from the inbuit function.

Comment: Did you get any error in the console? Where did you write the if statement.? You have to return the function in the service. I have written a controller and injected the service. Called the function service function. It is working.

Comment: Its actually a popup.. I am checking if condition outside this factory, so i'm using `gService.confirmDialog.onConfirm`

Comment: Added `code`return {confirmDialog:confirmDialog }`code` at the end of the gService. It is working for me.

Comment: @Matarishvan Something is not clear in your question. Please, I'm asking you to [edit] and explain what exactly **are you trying to achieve**, we need more macro details - Do you want to show this message **only once** and then check what was the check if the user confirmed it or not? You need to add context. That's will help us give you better solution. Thanks

Comment: @AlonEitan Basically, I have a confirm from `navigator.notification` which executes multiple time..  whenever it executes, i want to check in popup is executed or not outside the factory

Comment: @Matarishvan, you need to be more specific about this ques. Please do provide the scenario also when you want to test that condition? In short the info is insufficient to answer this ques.

Comment: @Matarishvan, The solition is correctly wroten and explained. Why you don't accepting answer ? To not give the bounty ? Open a bounty take attention collect answers and not give the bounty. It is not ethical.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### [**EMIT**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$emit) & [**BROADCAST**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast)

If you check `onConfirm` event that it will controll is `onConfirm` function defined on `gService.confirmDialog` object where the statement wroten. It is not async and promised job.

```
if(gService.confirmDialog.onConfirm){

}
```

---

You need to ***notify your listeners*** first. After that ***listen that event*** to do your job.

You can `broadcast` or `emit` an event to **scopes** that waiting for `onConfirm` event.

```
   angular.module('app').factory('gService',gService);
    function gService($rootScope, $filter, $window) {
        function confirmDialog(message, success, fail) {
            var confirmMessage = navigator.notification.confirm(
                    message,
                    onConfirm,
                    '',
                    [$filter('translate')('OK'), $filter('translate')('CANCEL')]
                );
            function onConfirm(index) {
                var result = index === 1 ? success() : fail();
                $rootScope.$emit('onConfirm', result); 
                //or
                //$rootScope.$broadcast('onConfirm', result); -> this goes downwards to all child scopes. Emit is upwarded.

            }
            return confirmMessage;
        }
    }
```

After that you should check if `onConfirm` event is triggered. This does the controll you need.

```
function onConfirmFunction( result ){ //You will get the success or fail methods result here... };

$rootScope.$on('onConfirm', onConfirmFunction);
```

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you do this.

```
angular.module('app').factory('gService',gService);
function gService($filter, $window) {
    var obj = {
        confirmDialog : confirmDialog,
        onConfirm : onConfirm,
    }
    obj.executed = false;
    function confirmDialog(message, success, fail) {
        var confirmMessage = navigator.notification.confirm(
                message,
                onConfirm,
                '',
                [$filter('translate')('OK'), $filter('translate')('CANCEL')]
            );
        function onConfirm(index) {         
            if(index===1){
                //I dont know you want function or returned value of function but you can use success() as well
                obj.executed = success;
                return success();
            }else{
                obj.executed = fail;
                return fail();
            }
        }
        return confirmMessage;
    }
    return obj;
}
```

you can check now..

> if(gService.executed){
>
> }

and I dont know if you forgot but you haven't returned anything from factory.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
angular.module('app').factory('gService', gService);
function gService($filter, $window) {
  var observers = [];
  function observeNotify(callback) {
    observers.push(callback);
  }
  function confirmDialog(message, success, fail) {
    var confirmMessage = navigator.notification.confirm(
      message,
      onConfirm,
      '',
      [$filter('translate')('OK'), $filter('translate')('CANCEL')],
    );
    function onConfirm(index) {
      var condition = index === 1;
      observers.forEach(function(observer) {
        observer(condition);
      });
      return condition ? success() : fail();
    }
    return confirmMessage;
  }
}
//Outside of the factory

gService.observeNotify(function(condition){
  console.log(condition);
});
```

This way you can register functions, that will be called during the execution of the `onConfirm` function

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are expecting? I am not sure what is the problem. Can you explain more detail?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>How AngularJS Works?</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="appCtrl">

  <p>Welcome to BooKart, we have collection of {{1 + ' Million'}} books.</p>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.factory('gService', gService);

    function gService($filter, $window) {
      function confirmDialog(message, success, fail) {
        alert("called");
        var confirmMessage = navigator.notification.confirm(
          message,
          onConfirm,
          '', [$filter('translate')('OK'), $filter('translate')('CANCEL')]
        );

        function onConfirm(index) {
          return index === 1 ? success() : fail();
        }
        return confirmMessage;
      }
      return {
        confirmDialog:confirmDialog
      }
    }

    app.controller("appCtrl", function ($scope, gService) {
      $scope.callFun = function () {
        if (gService.confirmDialog("", "","").onConfirm) {

        }
      };
      $scope.callFun();
    });
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: No. Actually the condition `gService.confirmDialog.onConfirm` i'm not able to check.. This is what i'm looking for.

Comment: *Is this what you are expecting? I am not sure what is the problem. Can you explain more detail?* Then don't answer. Instead, ask in the comments for the OP to clarify themselves and, if you decide to do so, flag for closure as "Unclear what you're asking".

Answer (score 2):

Convert onComfirm to a promise and do something after the promise is resolved.

```
function onConfirm(index) {
  return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
  index === 1 ? resolve(true) : reject(false);
  });
 }



  $scope.callFun = function () {
    gService.confirmDialog("", "","").onConfirm()
       .then(function(sucess) {
          successMethod();  
        }, function(error) {
           console.error('oh no');
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

basically you are not returning (reference to the code you shared) anything from the function `gService` (implementation of your factory), since its a `factory` you have to return something. your inner function `confirmDialog` return an object, but the outer function `gServive` dosen't returns anything. The way you want to execute it, you have to return either `confirmDialog` callback and have to execute in the injecting end like

`if(gServive(<..args...>).onConfirm())`

and in case toy are returning a object then

`return {confirmDialog: confirmDialog(...<args>...)}`

and then in the injecting end

`if(gService.confirmDialog.onConfirm)`

**Note**: That your onConfirm is a function, by calling it, it will return something, so it has to ve invoked with `(...)`, it is actually sounds like an event attacher function which will take a callback and fires on complete, but your code dosen't says that. in that case you can maintain a promise, and in `onConfirm` call take a callback as argument, and then pass it to `then` of that promise, and whenever you filled its time to confirm, just resolve that promise.